# Most efficient way to show another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app that has a main view controller (login controller). If the authorization is completed I will show another controller(tabBarController) to the user. I've made it in this way:

AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    LogInViewController *logInController = [[[LogInViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    _tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init] ;

    SearchViewController *searchController = [[[SearchViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    CabinetViewController *cabinetController = [[[CabinetViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    HelpViewController *helpController = [[[HelpViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    CatalogViewController *catalogController = [[[CatalogViewController alloc] init] autorelease];    

    NSArray *controllerArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cabinetController, catalogController, searchController, helpController, nil];

    [_tabBarController setViewControllers:controllerArray];

    //[navController setViewControllers:controllerArray];
    [self.window setRootViewController:logInController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

And then on the button event I've made this:

```
-(void)logInUser:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegate.window setRootViewController:delegate.tabBarController];
    [delegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

How to do this kind of stuff in more efficient way??? Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're asking what's the most *efficient* way, that's easy.  Use **Storyboards**.

This is literally exactly the problem Storyboards were designed to solve.  You can create all your view controllers, set many of the desired properties - including the fact that you want the *outer* Navigation Controller to hide its navigation bar - in the storyboard itself and you'll get a realtime editor that you can bounce ideas off.  The best part?  You can do everything you described in your question using Storyboards in *zero* lines of code.  So that's zero lines of code to write and maintain.  True story.  I'll prove it!

I created an imitation of what you describe in your question in the storyboard below:
[image: Storyboard]

This results in the following application in the simulator:

[image: iOS Simulator]

The best part, this is a screenshot of the entirety of the code in this application:

[image: App Delegate]

I don't think it gets much more efficient than this.  If you're new to storyboards I highly recommend reading the fantastic beginner's guide from Ray Wenderlich, [Beginning Storyboards in iOS 5](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1).

Comment: Wow. Your answer is great, thanks you very much. But :) I know about storyboards and so on - I need to support iOs 4.3 in this app =((( Maybe you know how to do it using xib's in most efficient way (then mine variant) and uses less memory. Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)HelpClicked:(id)sender
{

     _tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]initWithNibName:@"UITabBarController" bundle:nil]; ;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_tabBarController animated:YES];

}
```

try this one...

Comment: It is bad to do as it because  viewController of tabBarController also has navigation controller so it wrapper to previous use NavController.

Comment: But won't it create the situation where the user can go back in the navigation stack to the original `loginView`? Instead, the navigation controller's `viewControllers` array property should be set with `tabBarController` as the only object.

Comment: he just want to go to next view controller he asking telling a way i just tell him that way...